# How to get all rows from a SQL table before a change in column string?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have these 2 tables and their inserts:

```
create table #JobFailureConfig (
    JobId int not null,
    JobName varchar(128) not null);
go

insert into #JobFailureConfig values (2, 'CopyOverFileJob');
insert into #JobFailureConfig values (3, 'ExcludeFromWarehouseJob');
go

create table #Job(
    id int,
    JobId int,
    CreateDtTm datetimeoffset,
    StatusDtTm datetimeoffset,
    StatusName varchar(128));
go

insert into #Job values (47022087, 3, '2020-05-07 18:44:35.7327 -07:00', '2020-05-07 18:44:36.6599 -07:00','Failed');
insert into #Job values (47022092, 3, '2020-05-07 18:44:47.1431 -07:00', '2020-05-07 18:44:47.2599 -07:00','Failed');
insert into #Job values (47022097, 3, '2020-05-07 18:45:36.6888 -07:00', '2020-05-07 18:45:36.8439 -07:00','Failed');
insert into #Job values (47022088, 3, '2020-05-07 18:46:35.7327 -07:00', '2020-05-07 18:47:36.6599 -07:00','Finished');
insert into #Job values (47022087, 3, '2020-05-07 18:44:35.7327 -07:00', '2020-05-13 18:44:36.6599 -07:00','Failed');
insert into #Job values (47022092, 3, '2020-05-07 18:44:47.1431 -07:00', '2020-05-13 18:44:47.2599 -07:00','Failed');

insert into #Job values (98234237, 2, '2020-05-01 18:44:35.7327 -07:00', '2020-05-01 18:44:36.6599 -07:00','Finished');
insert into #Job values (98234238, 2, '2020-05-03 18:44:35.7327 -07:00', '2020-05-03 18:44:36.6599 -07:00','Failed');
insert into #Job values (98234238, 2, '2020-05-03 18:44:35.7327 -07:00', '2020-04-03 18:44:36.6599 -07:00','Failed');
go
```

I have this query to partition them by `JobId` and order them by `JobId` and `StatusDtTm`:

```
select
    j.Id,
    j.JobId,
    jfc.JobName,
    j.StatusName,
    CreateDtTm = format(cast(CreateDtTm as datetime), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),
    StatusDtTm = format(cast(StatusDtTm as datetime), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'),
    row_number() over (Partition by j.JobId order by j.JobId, j.StatusDtTm desc) as JobFailureId
from #Job j
join #JobFailureConfig jfc
    on j.JobId = jfc.JobId;
go
```

[image]

I want to fetch only the rows where the Job last finished per job. Basically get all the records per job before it last finished (highlighted in green). I can't seem to figure out what to add in the where clause here to get the highlighted result. Can someone help please?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One approach is to add the following column to your query:

```
count(case when statusname = 'Finished' then 1 end)
   over(partition by j.jobid
        order by j.StatusDtTm
        rows between unbounded preceding and current row) sel
```

This new field `sel` will have a nonzero value for the highlighted rows, where a current or a previous `StatusName` for that job ID has the value 'Finished'; otherwise, the value will be zero.

The full query to output only the highlighted records is then:

```
with cte as
(
    select
       j.Id,
       j.JobId,
       jfc.JobName,
       j.StatusName,
       format(cast(CreateDtTm as datetime), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as CreateDtTm,
       format(cast(StatusDtTm as datetime), 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss') as StatusDtTm,
       row_number() over (Partition by j.JobId order by j.JobId, j.StatusDtTm desc) as JobFailureId,
       count(case when statusname = 'Finished' then 1 end)
         over(partition by j.jobid
              order by j.StatusDtTm
              rows between unbounded preceding and current row) sel
   from #Job j
   join #JobFailureConfig jfc
       on j.JobId = jfc.JobId
)
select Id, JobId, JobName, StatusName, CreateDtTm, StatusDtTm, JobFailureId
from cte
where sel=1
order by jobid, jobfailureid
```

Comment: @NitinDeb . . . This answer will return rows that have `FINISHED`, even when that is not the last row -- which your question specifically states you are asking for.  If you know that `FINISHED` is always last, then this is not the simplest solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to know if a row is finished for a `jobid`, you can use the logic:

```
sum(case when statusname = 'Finished' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by jobid)
```

In the context of your query, you could write it as:

```
with q as (
      . . .
     )
select q.*
from (select q.*, 
             sum(case when statusname = 'Finished' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by jobid) as cnt
      from q
     ) q
where cnt >= 1;
```

If you know that `'FINISHED'` is the last row -- or if you do not care (despite the question) -- then this solves the problem and no window frame is required for the window function.

If you specifically want the *last* row -- which is what your question is asking for ("I want to fetch only the rows where the Job last finished per job.") -- then you can use the `statusdttim` which presumably defines "last":

```
with q as (
      . . .
     )
select q.*
from (select q.*, 
             max(case when statusname = 'Finished' then statusdttim end) over (partition by jobid) as finished_dtm,
             max(statusdttim) over (partition by jobid) as last_dtm
      from q
     ) q
where last_dtm = finished_dtm;
```

Comment: if you see my screenshot, let's consider the first 3 rows, they have the same job ordered by StatusDtTm desc. Basically I want to fetch all the records from now to the past where it last Finished hence only the first two rows. Same is the case with the second job. It is okay if we cannot use CTE, I'm fine with using temp tables as well.

Comment: @NitinDeb . . . This sentence:  "I want to fetch only the rows where the Job last finished per job" does not seem to accurately explain what you want then.

Comment: my bad, should have framed it better but the screenshot shows the result that I want and that was pretty much clear.

Comment: @NitinDeb . . . It appears to be drf's answer.